# How do you install the optional channel on RHEL version 7?

Tags: linux, redhat, puppet

To install Puppet Master on RedHat Linux version 7, you need to install an optional channel. Can someone provide directions on how to do this?  I want to install Puppet Master. I tried to install Puppet Master without the optional channel. The main thing that is wrong is that I cannot start puppetmaster.

I run this: /etc/init.d/puppetmaster restart

But I get this: -bash: /etc/init.d/puppetmaster: No such file or directory

The Puppet Labs website has a broken link for installing the optional channel.  There must be directions somewhere else.

Comment: use this https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/puppetlabs_package_repositories.html#for-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-derivatives

Answer (score 3):

You can add the optional channel from the command line by running the command:

```
 rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7
```

You can run this command as root or use sudo.

Comment: I ran it as root.  But this is what I got:              Usage: rhn-channel [options]

rhn-channel: error: no such option: -d